# Does restarting Samba corrupt files being transferred?

Tags: samba

Will restarting samba corrupt files that are being transfered at the time of restart ?

Does Samba first do a clean close on all files before restarting or simply restarts abruptly ?

Alternatively, is there a clean way to restart SAMBA such that no files are corrupted in the process ?

Answer (score 3):

Restarting a service is sending a terminate signal to the process, which in turn should gracefully close and shutdown and then start again. 
So, there should be no risk of corruption to files.

Comment: This is, unfortunately, not true. Consider an application that's in the middle of modifying a file. Even if samba closes gracefully, the application that's modifying the file may stop in the middle of the operation when it can't write to samba anymore.

Comment: Samba active connections are reconnected on restart. There might be some edge cases that might not comply.

Comment: The problem is that the application may not still be there when the Samba server restarts. For example, you may be in the middle of overwriting one instance of a file with a new instance of a file and wind up timing out with the file containing a bit of each.